# PHP variables hides string values

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a 12 digit password but the PHP variable sometimes prints only 1 or 3 digits but when I count the string of variable it shows 12.

```
 $caps = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $special = '!@#$%^&*<>?';
    $small = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $digit = '0123456789';

    $capsLength = strlen($caps);
    $specialLength = strlen($special);
    $smallLength = strlen($small);
    $digitLength = strlen($digit);

    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $randomString .= str_shuffle($caps[mt_rand(0, $capsLength - 1)] . $special[mt_rand(0, $specialLength - 1)] . $small[mt_rand(0, $smallLength - 1)] . $digit[mt_rand(0, $digitLength - 1)]);

    }
    echo strlen($randomString).'</br>';
    echo $randomString;
```

Comment: Are you viewing this in a browser? If your string contains `<` then it's probably trying to render it as an HTML tag. Try viewing the source of the page instead, they should be there. If you want it to display properly then you'll need to escape it.

Comment: Yes, or `var_dump()` the string.

Comment: or try with `echo htmlspecialchars($randomString);`

Comment: Thanks, @ADyson. That was the issue. Now it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that there are some characters like `<>` that the browser could interpret as HTML tags and try to render them as elements of the DOM.

The solution is to use [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to convert these special characters to HTML entities as [@ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65934326/php-variables-hides-string-values#comment116577064_65934326) suggested.

You just have to change this line:

```
echo $randomString;
```

To this:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($randomString);
```